# Modal does not scale on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am using bootstrap to make my entire website but the only problem I have seen is that my modal does not scale and pushes towards the center which is not displayed on a mobile device.

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="player_box" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
<h3 id="player_box_header"></h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="player_box_content">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<div class="pull-left" id="social_share_box"></div>
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
```

I am using default bootstrap CSS so I am not sure why it is not being responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the @media css3 types to refine based on the device resolution

for example

@media (max-width: 480px) and (max-height: 200px){.modal{ height: 150px}}

Comment: Can't believe I did not think of doing that thank you very much fixed my problem :D